# Pycharm error - OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, pycharm, oserror

I am trying to run my program on Pycharm but I am getting the following error

```
C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:/Users/I323017/PycharmProjects/question_answering_kinnal/src/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/I323017/PycharmProjects/question_answering_kinnal/src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.dataset import PrepareDataSet
  File "C:\Users\I323017\PycharmProjects\question_answering_kinnal\src\dataset.py", line 7, in <module>
    from transformers import SquadExample, squad_convert_examples_to_features, AlbertTokenizer
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .benchmark_utils import (
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\benchmark_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .file_utils import is_tf_available, is_torch_available
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\file_utils.py", line 38, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why am I getting the `OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found` when everything seems to be in place. Does this have to do something with the interpreter? Currently, I am using my Conda interpreter in Pycharm

Actually, I had a lot of unwanted packages and so I did a `conda clean --yes --all` and my Pycharm is not working since then.

Comment: I would just use the regular interpreter as your module could've been installed there

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have more than one interpreter, you probably installed this module on the other interpreter. I would switch interpreters and see if it works. In the future, if you wish to avoid these issues it would be wise to use a virtual environment.

Comment: Using a virtual environment creates a problem during pytorch installation

Comment: and there is no solution for this issue? that sounds very strange

Answer (score 1):

From https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cannot-import-torch-on-jupyter-notebook/79334 the problem seems to be because of installing the GPU version of PyTorch. In case there is no GPU driver in the host system, it is recommended to install the CPU version of Pytorch using

```
# Conda
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
# Pip
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to enable Windows Long Path. After restarting everything works.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: This only happens with Win 10 because it disables long path by default. You can enable it in the windows settings I think regedit. Microsoft has detailed steps on its website.